# How to implement password based hybrid encryption in java?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm currently working on an Android project for developing a Hybrid File Encryption. From this [site](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html), I've already created a hybrid encryption which **only able to encrypt text/string**. While **all the keys are automatically generated within the code**. Any idea on how to make the keys to be user input password based and able to encrypt files?

Here is the code:

```
    // Some codes here

    // Create key pair (public and private key) for RSA encryption and decryption
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "RSA key pair error");
    }
}

private void encHybrid() throws GeneralSecurityException {

    // Create random secret key with AES algorithm
    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

    kg.init(128, sr) ;
    SecretKey cipherKey = kg.generateKey() ;

    // Encrypt secret key asymmetry algorithm (RSA)
    encryptedSecretKey = encrypt(cipherKey.getEncoded(), kp.getPublic());

    textHybrid = etHybrid.getText().toString();

    // Encrypt inputted text/string with symmetry algorithm using encrypted secret key
    encryptedData = encrypt(textHybrid.getBytes(), cipherKey);

}

// Method to encrypt the text/string
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt, SecretKey key)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES") ;
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key) ;
    return cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
}

// Method to encrypt the secret key
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt, PublicKey key)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA") ;
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key) ;
    return cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
}

private void decryptHybrid() throws GeneralSecurityException {

    // Decrypt secret key with private key
    byte[] decryptedSecretKey = decrypt(encryptedSecretKey, kp.getPrivate()) ;

    // Decrypted secret key will be stored in sKey
    SecretKey sKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedSecretKey, "AES") ;
    textHybrid = etHybrid.getText().toString();

    // Decrypt encrypted text/string with decrypted secret key
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(encryptedData, sKey) ;

}

// Method to decrypt the text/string
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt, SecretKey key)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher deCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES") ;
    deCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key) ;
    return deCipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);
}

// Method to decrypt the secret key
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt, PrivateKey key)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher deCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA") ;
    deCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key) ;
    return deCipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);
}
```

Comment: You Need to create Your own RSA keys based on entered value or You trying to get Android password and create based on it key?

Comment: Yes, here is the @owlstead quote about [that site](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html):"The idiot that wrote that should be shot and keelhauled, then shot again to be sure."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really want to generate the key pair from the password. The problem with that scheme is that there is no way to trust the public key. What is usually done is to *encrypt the private key* with a secret (symmetric) key that has been generated from a password.

So, *in addition to the hybrid encryption* you would have a scheme that does it entirely the other way around. It's a bit of code, but it should be readable enough. Or you could use PGP, which essentially performs the same kind of operations.

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class PassphraseWrapRSA {
    private static KeyPair generateRSAKeyPair(final int size) {
        KeyPairGenerator kpgen;
        try {
            kpgen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        kpgen.initialize(size);
        return kpgen.generateKeyPair();
    }

    public static byte[] generateSalt() {
        final SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
        final byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        rng.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    private static SecretKey deriveAESKey(final byte[] salt,
            final char[] password) {
        try {
            final SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            final KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
            final SecretKey keyWrapKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            final SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(keyWrapKey.getEncoded(),
                    "AES");
            return secret;

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] encryptRSAPrivateKey(final RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey,
            final SecretKey aesKey) {
        try {
            final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

            final SecureRandom ivGen = new SecureRandom();
            final byte[] iv = new byte[c.getBlockSize()];
            ivGen.nextBytes(iv);
            c.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            final byte[] wrappedKey = c.wrap(rsaPrivateKey);
            return concat(iv, wrappedKey);
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] wrapRSAPrivateKey(final String passphrase,
            final RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey) {
        // --- generate salt
        final byte[] newSalt = generateSalt();

        // --- derive symmetric key from salt and password
        final SecretKey aesKey = deriveAESKey(newSalt,
                passphrase.toCharArray());


        final byte[] encryptedPrivate = encryptRSAPrivateKey(rsaPrivateKey, aesKey);
        final byte[] saltedAndEncryptedPrivate = concat(newSalt,
                encryptedPrivate);
        return saltedAndEncryptedPrivate;
    }

    private static RSAPrivateKey decryptRSAPrivateKey(final byte[] encryptedRSAPrivateKey,
            final SecretKey aesKey) throws InvalidKeyException {
        try {
            final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

            int offset = 0;
            final byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedRSAPrivateKey, 0,
                    c.getBlockSize());
            offset += c.getBlockSize();

            c.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            final Key key = c.unwrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedRSAPrivateKey, offset,
                    encryptedRSAPrivateKey.length), "RSA", Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY);
            return (RSAPrivateKey) key;
        } catch (final InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static RSAPrivateKey unwrapRSAPrivateKey(final String passphrase,
            final byte[] saltedAndEncryptedPrivate) throws InvalidKeyException {
        int offset = 0;
        final byte[] backSalt = Arrays.copyOfRange(saltedAndEncryptedPrivate,
                offset, 16);
        offset += 16;
        final SecretKey backAESKey = deriveAESKey(backSalt,
                passphrase.toCharArray());
        final byte[] backEncryptedPrivateKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(
                saltedAndEncryptedPrivate, offset,
                saltedAndEncryptedPrivate.length);
        final RSAPrivateKey decryptedPrivate = decryptRSAPrivateKey(
                backEncryptedPrivateKey, backAESKey);
        return decryptedPrivate;
    }

    public static RSAPublicKey decodeRSAPublicKey(
            final byte[] x509EncodedPUblicKey) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
        try {
            final KeyFactory rsaPublicKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            final PublicKey pubKey = rsaPublicKeyFactory
                    .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(x509EncodedPUblicKey));
            return (RSAPublicKey) pubKey;
        } catch (final InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] encodeRSAPublicKey(final RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey) {
        return rsaPublicKey.getEncoded();
    }

    private static byte[] concat(final byte[] a, final byte[] a2) {
        final byte[] result = new byte[a.length + a2.length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(a2, 0, result, a.length, a2.length);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        // --- not required for Java 8
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // --- setup key pair (generated in advance)
        final String passphrase = "owlstead";
        final KeyPair kp = generateRSAKeyPair(1024);
        final RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
        final RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();

        // --- encode and wrap
        byte[] x509EncodedRSAPublicKey = encodeRSAPublicKey(rsaPublicKey);
        final byte[] saltedAndEncryptedPrivate = wrapRSAPrivateKey(
                passphrase, rsaPrivateKey);

        // --- decode and unwrap
        final RSAPublicKey retrievedRSAPublicKey = decodeRSAPublicKey(x509EncodedRSAPublicKey);
        final RSAPrivateKey retrievedRSAPrivateKey = unwrapRSAPrivateKey(passphrase,
                saltedAndEncryptedPrivate);

        // --- check result
        System.out.println(retrievedRSAPublicKey);
        System.out.println(retrievedRSAPrivateKey);
    }
}
```

WARNING: for demonstration purposes only, please implement using classes and a more flexible method of handling the protocol (include e.g. a version number) etc.

Comment: Using native crypto is fine if it is available. With native code there is always the chance of buffer overruns, so it never hurts to do some more input validation. Neither one is stronger, and in this case you should use *both*. You need the PKI for key management, and the symmetric encryption for protecting the private key.Then use hybrid encryption for the ciphertext itself. IE use this code *in addition* to your own code.

Comment: Well, not all phones support all encryption algorithms and using Bouncy Castle is more flexible, I'll go with it. The question is, is it possible if the user given option to choose the algorithms itself, like to choose which symmetric and asymmetric algorithm they want and pass it over the code?

Comment: Of course it is *possible*. It would however require a more flexible approach, a special message format and - probably the most difficult part to obtain - educated users :) You may look at e.g. PGP for in that case - no need to do it all yourself.

Comment: hi, i am looking for string encryption for android **Nought**. **Is above code working for android nought.**

Comment: There are no special constructs within above code, so it should work. Why not give it a spin instead of asking, probably less work.